# Xamarin.Android SDK and Xamarin.iOS SDK missing during Xamarin Studio Installation - Windows 8

Tags: sdk, xamarin, failed-installation

As well as Visual Studio 2013 extention Xamarin is missing.

Do need to track these down and install manually? I've been trying but I'm a bit lost!

Thanks.

UPDATE: I found Xamarin Studio in the Program Files. A search did not bring it up. It seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you found it, also you may want to take a look at the Add/Remove Programs and there you will see both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin Studio. Xamarin.iOS can install but will not run without a Mac machine in the network it can connect to to build.

Good luck with Xamarin - it is the most exciting thing currently in cross platform mobile technology.